# Pincode to check shipping serviceability in the checkout page magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

Pin code to check shipping serviceability in the Checkout page magento.

Comment: i am using two three extension but all of them are in product page. i want to check on checkout page. anyone can help me

Comment: did you checked this : http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html

Comment: have u tried so far?

Comment: yes, first of all i used this. it is working on admin properly but not showing on front end

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari you need to create this code in static block : `<p>{{block type ="core/template" template = "checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml"}}</p>` and call that static block in checkout page phtml file

Comment: i created a static block with your code and call it on checkout phtml page but still it is not working.  can you reply me please

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari try with this code in checkout page : `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('check')->toHtml();` [  where check = block code"

Comment: i am using it. i have only app folder for this extension am i right or wrong can you tell me ...nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.ht‌​ml

Comment: sorry i did not get what is meaning of check in above code or what is block code

Comment: as i have installed this extension in my website add to cart button is not working.

Comment: when 2 or more members commened on your post, than you need to tag the user name to send notification as @ErSarveshVTiwari

Comment: go to static blocks , when you click on create new block , you can see `Identifier *` you need to give "check" for that.... @ErSarveshVTiwari

Comment: only `app` folder is fine, thats not problem, for me , `add to cart` button worked fine, also are you sure this extension is giving problem of `add to cart` , try disabling this extension and check once `add to cart` is working or not..... you can uninstall under `app/etc/modules` folder....

Comment: yes as i uninstall this extension now add to cart button is working properly.

Comment: i am using one page checkout i paste above code in onepage phtml and also i have created static block i used identifier as check in above code but still it is showing on product details page not checkout page

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari try template path hints as in this link : http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints & add the code in proper file....

Comment: i have created a new static block with code <p>{{block type ="core/template" template = "checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml"}}</p>

Comment: and than paste in one page checkout phtml echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('delivery')->toHtml();

Comment: am i right can you check and please tell me. first of tell me when i am installing this extension my add to cart buttons are not working

Comment: i fallow your instruction but it is still not working please reply me i am waiting your response

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46721/discussion-on-question-by-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-pincode-to-check-shipping-servicea).